# Possible to register static only protocols?

Tags: swinject

Unfortunately, some libraries only have static methods to them. Is it possible to make Swinject register a type to return a type instead of an instance of a type? Makes it hard to stub out static only libraries for testing.

Answer (score 0):

In the current state of the Swinject this is unfortunately not possible. One of the ways you could work around this would be creating a custom type provider:

```
protocol LibraryProtocol {}
class Library: LibraryProtocol {}

class LibraryProvider {
    let library: LibraryProtocol.Type
    init(_ library: LibraryProtocol.Type) { self.library = library }
}

container.register(LibraryProvider.self) { _ in LibraryProvider(Library.self) }
```